# Insert String value into Database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've got my passwords to be hashed in my ASP.NET Webforms.

How do I then enter the hashed password into the database via a string?

```
SqlConnection dbCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConMotorstore"].ConnectionString);

dbCon.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [user] VALUES (@firstName, @surname, @email, @username, @passwordHash)", dbCon);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstName", firstNameTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("surname", surnameTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", emailTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", usernameTxt.Text);

string passwordHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(passwordTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.ToString("passwordHash");

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I knew I couldn't use `.AddWithValue` and thought of `.ToString` may have been the one to use.

I am new to C#.

Thanks.

Comment: "I knew I couldn't use .AddWithValue "  Why did you think that?

Comment: As a side note, you should be wrapping your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` statements in `using` blocks.

Comment: if you just hash your password to a string and want to store that string, you can indeed just use `AddWithValue`. What you're doing up there `cmd.Parameters.ToString("passwordHash")` will not accomplish much, because the `ToString()` method just returns a (formatted) string and doesn't do any assignment internally, besides it will try to take "passwordHash" as the format string wich doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What is the problem with `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("passwordHash", passwordHash);`?

Comment: @AmitJoshi http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
   SqlConnection dbCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConMotorstore"].ConnectionString);
{
    dbCon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [user] VALUES (@firstName,@surname,@email,@username,@passwordHash)", dbCon);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstName", firstNameTxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("surname", surnameTxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", emailTxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", usernameTxt.Text);
    string passwordHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(passwordTxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("passwordHash", passwordHash);


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks @mjwills! Works fine, never thought of trying that.